# jQuery-pjax vs history.js to load specific content when clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I need to ajaxify my site, like loading a spinner or something for **rendering specific content in a page when clicking a link**.

I have found 2 good jQuery plugins.

- https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax
- https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

**What is their main difference**? It seems they are doing the same job. Well, maybe one uses the ajax then returns the html (pjax) and one uses a so-called html5 push state or something.

**Is there another way doing this**? (simpler or with only jQuery) I think it's too overkill to use either of those plugins (but I'm not sure if there is a simpler way for doing this).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

author of History.js here.

- History.js is extremely low-level and just focuses on providing a cross-browser compatible interface for the HTML5 History API
- PJAX is high-level and utilises the HTML5 History API to provide a an interface for upgrading your website with AJAX using the two technologies.

So you can get PJAX to use History.js so that it supports cross browsers. There is actually a request about this [here](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/issues/3).

Though that doesn't mean History.js leaves you on your own either in regards to AJAX, it does provide you with a high-level sample for using History.js with AJAX [here](https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify) and you can find more info about how that was created [here](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling). Essentially that gist and PJAX do the same thing, but they have gone about them in different ways.

In regards to simpler, History.js is the most low-level basic shortest simple thing you can get which will ensure the HTML5 History API works in all browsers - that's it's aim, to be as low-level and compact as possible so other things can extend it the way they want - such as PJAX or that Gist.

Comment: +1 Thanks @balupton, Suppose if I pick this URL `http://history.js/demo/?state=3`, and pass it on to somebody who has HTML 4 browser. Will he get redirected to `http://history.js/demo/#?state=3`?